# Draw arc segments using UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, geometry, calayer, uibezierpath

I know there are lots of example related to `UIBezierPath`, but I am very confused about the angles to use to draw arc, my requirement is like the **image** below to draw arcs. The length and angle should be calculated as per total number.

[image]

Right now I have created a function which draws the arcs see below

```
-(void)createCircleWithStartAngle:(int)startAngle endAngle:(int)endAngle name:(NSString *)name{

    UIView *subView=_viewContainer;

    // Set up the shape of the circle
    int radius = 125;

    CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    // Make a circular shape

    UIBezierPath *path=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(radius, radius) radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];


    circle.path = [path CGPath];


    // Center the shape in self.view
    circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(subView.bounds)-radius,
                                  CGRectGetMidY(subView.bounds)-radius);


    circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

    //making line end cap round
    circle.lineCap=kCALineCapRound;


    UIColor *strokeColor;
    if([name isEqualToString:@"A"])
        strokeColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
    else if([name isEqualToString:@"B"])
        strokeColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:40.0/255.0 green:180.0/255.0 blue:213.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    else if([name isEqualToString:@"C"])
        strokeColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0 green:240/255.0 blue:240/255.0 alpha:1.0];


    circle.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor;
    circle.lineWidth = 10;

    // Add to parent layer
    [subView.layer addSublayer:circle];



    // Configure animation
    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = 1.0;
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;


    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];


    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

    // Add the animation to the circle
    [circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
}
```

I am calling the above function 3 times so it creates 3 arc segments like below

```
    float angleToStart=DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(120);
    float angleToEnd=DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(270);
    //investment
    [self createCircleWithStartAngle:angleToStart endAngle:angleToEnd name:@"A"];



    float factor=total/bvalue;
    angleToStart=angleToEnd;
    angleToEnd=180/factor;
    angleToEnd=DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angleToEnd);

    [self createCircleWithStartAngle:angleToStart endAngle:angleToEnd name:@"B"];



    angleToStart=DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angleToEnd);
    angleToEnd=DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(60);
    [self createCircleWithStartAngle:angleToStart endAngle:angleToEnd name:@"C"];
```

as a result I am getting output like below

[image]

which is somehow correct, but not 100%, scenarios as below

1. The starting point in **dark gray** is not same as endpoint **off white**
2. The **dark gray** portion should be half circled always, and blue should follow it with factor.
3. The **off white** segement to fill the rest portion to the end.

Can anyone help me to get the values correct? So that it draws

Thanks.

---

**Update(Adding complete solution to draw similar arc)**

The function below responsible for drawing the arc for supplied angles

```
-(void)createCircleWithStartAngle:(float)startAngle endAngle:(float)endAngle chartSection:(ChartSection)section lineCap:(NSString *const)lineCap{

    UIView *subView=_circleView;

    // Set up the shape of the circle
    float radius = _circleView.bounds.size.width/2.0;//125.0;

    CAShapeLayer *circle = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    // Make a circular shape

    UIBezierPath *path=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(radius, radius) radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];



    circle.path = [path CGPath];


    // Center the shape in self.view
    circle.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(subView.bounds)-radius,
                                  CGRectGetMidY(subView.bounds)-radius);

    // Configure the apperence of the circle
    circle.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;


    UIColor *strokeColor;

    circle.lineCap=lineCap;

    switch (section) {
        case ChartSectionA:
            strokeColor=[UIColor darkGrayColor];
            break;
        case ChartSectionB:
            strokeColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:40.0/255.0 green:180.0/255.0 blue:213.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            break;
        case ChartSectionC:
            strokeColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:240/255.0 green:240/255.0 blue:240/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            break;
        default:
            strokeColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:40.0/255.0 green:180.0/255.0 blue:213.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            break;
    }



    circle.strokeColor = strokeColor.CGColor;
    circle.lineWidth = 10;

    //keep the arrangement intact with the indexes..
    [subView.layer insertSublayer:circle atIndex:section];



    // Configure animation
    CABasicAnimation *drawAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
    drawAnimation.duration            = 1.0;
    drawAnimation.repeatCount         = 1.0;

    // Animate from no part of the stroke being drawn to the entire stroke being drawn
    drawAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    drawAnimation.toValue   = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];

    // Experiment with timing to get the appearence to look the way you want
    drawAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];

    // Add the animation to the circle
    [circle addAnimation:drawAnimation forKey:@"drawCircleAnimation"];
}
```

The function below calculates angle as per values and supplies to the function above..

```
-(void)createArcWithValueOfSectionA:(float)amountA sectionB:(float)amountB sectionC:(float)amountC{

    if(amountA<0.0)
        amountA=0.0;

    if(amountB<0.0)
        amountB=0.0;

    if(amountC<0.0)
        amountC=0.0;


    float baseStartAngle=120.0;//base start angle
    float baseEndAngle=60.0;//base end angle
    float totalAngle=300.0;//total angle to be calculated

    float sectionAPercent = amountA/(amountA+amountB+amountC);
    float sectionBPercent = amountB/(amountA+amountB+amountC);


    float angleToStart=DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(baseStartAngle);
    float angleToEnd=0.0;

    if(sectionAPercent<0)
        sectionAPercent=0.0;

    if(sectionBPercent<0)
        sectionBPercent=0.0;


    //calculate sectionA end angle with the value inputted
    angleToEnd=baseStartAngle + sectionAPercent * totalAngle;

    //we need to determine cap style as per data
    NSString *lineCap=kCALineCapRound;



    //Section A
    [self createCircleWithStartAngle:angleToStart endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angleToEnd) chartSection:ChartSectionA lineCap:lineCap];


    //next drawing for bidding should start from investment end angle
    angleToStart=angleToEnd;

    angleToEnd=sectionBPercent * totalAngle;

    angleToEnd=angleToStart+angleToEnd;

    lineCap=kCALineCapSquare;

    //Section B
    [self createCircleWithStartAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angleToStart) endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angleToEnd) chartSection:ChartSectionB lineCap:lineCap];

    //next drawing for sectionC should start from sectionB end angle
    angleToStart=angleToEnd;


    lineCap=kCALineCapRound;

    //draw Section C amount till end
    angleToEnd=DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(baseEndAngle);
    [self createCircleWithStartAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angleToStart) endAngle:angleToEnd chartSection:ChartSectionC lineCap:lineCap];

}
```

### Hope it helps someone.

Comment: Hi, what is this?  "float factor=total/bvalue;"
 can u please tell me? Also, I kept CGFloat, still circle is not properly completed. Its looks like as you shown above.

Comment: @SagarSukode Leave that part of question, I have updated the complete solution as per my discussion with Rob, reload and check my solution, it will surely help you with similar problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're using integers for your angles, but you're dealing with radians:

```
- (void)createCircleWithStartAngle:(int)startAngle endAngle:(int)endAngle name:(NSString *)name;
```

Use floating point (e.g. `CGFloat`) for your angles.

Comment: How dumb I am, yes drawing is correct now after I change it to float. Can you help me with getting the angle factor correct?

Comment: I have 3 values A,B,C. For ex. A=100, B=25, C=75. `A=Dark Gray draws upto angle 270`, `B=a portion of A in blue which starts drawing from angle 270`, the end angle of B to be calculated based on value of A. And C is drawn after B ends till angle 60. So I need to calculate endAngle of B.

Comment: So the angle from 270 to 60 to be distributed with the distributed values of B and C.

Comment: @iphonic - Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78835/discussion-between-rob-and-iphonic).